# PHP won't send the data to my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm brand new to PHP and just trying to create a very basic registration form but when I click submit it won't create the data in my database.

```
<form action"signup.php" method="post">
  username:<input type="text" name="n"><br />
  password:<input type="password" name="p"><br />
  id      :<input type="text" name="id"><br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>   


<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db   = mysql_select_db("myth", $conn);
?>

<?php
$user = $_POST['n'];
$pass = $_POST['p'];
$id   = $_POST['id'];
$sql  = "INSERT into phplogin values(" . $id . ",'" . $user . "','" . $pass . "')";
$query = mysql_query();

if(!$query)
    echo "failed ".mysql_error();
else           
    echo "successful";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually running the query - you need to call `mysql_query($sql)`.

Note that your code is quite vulnerable to things like SQL injection, and mysql_query is a deprecated function in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have not to use `mysql_*` command as they are deprecated; use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Second, you have to pass your string at method. In your case: `$result = mysql_query($sql);`

Remember that `$result` will return a resource that you have to fetch for obtain your rows

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
// here, you have your rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your script should be like this

```
<?php
    // create connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    // check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
         printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
         exit();
    }

    $user = $_POST['n'];
    $pass = $_POST['p'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];      

    $sql = "INSERT into phplogin values('$id','$user','$pass')";
    if($mysqli->query($query)) {
         printf("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
    } else {
         printf("Failed ".$mysqli->error);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

And yes don't use mysql_* as it's deprecated, use mysqli_ or PDO instead.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the problem of mysql injection and that mysql_* is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mysqli_query` as it is better than mysql_query...

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myth")or die("connection to database problem");

$user = $_POST['n'];
$pass = $_POST['p'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO phplogin VALUES (".$id.",'".$user."','".$pass."')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)or die("query error");

if(false===$query)
    echo "<br/>".mysqli_error($conn)."<br/><br/><br/>";
    else
    echo "<br/>done ";
?>
```

If there is any problem in connection the `connection to database problem` should occur

Comment: ah iv seen what i did wrong looking at this code, sadly hasnt fixed my problem, im begging to think this is a probem elsewere other than my code :( could there be an issue in mysql ?

Comment: Why is mysqli_* better? Please add an explanation!

Comment: mysqli is better because it has features such as Object-oriented interface - support for prepared statements - support for multiple statements - support for transactions - enhanced debugging capabilities - embedded server support.

Comment: tried the new code but still nothing, when i click submit nothing happens, the page loads for a split second but nothing after :( no errors and no query

Comment: still absolutely nothing is happening, i really dont understand this :S

Comment: getting these errors on the form page

Notice: Undefined index: n in C:\xampp\htdocs\myth\signup.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\myth\signup.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\myth\signup.php on line 6
query error